# How to make multiple plots of individual observations with background (splsda model) in R from a list?

Tags: r, list, plot, lapply

I am performing a splsda-model in R on 10 dataframes (data of 10 study areas), stored as a list (`datalist`). All these dataframes are similar, with the same variables, but just different values.

```
> head(datalist[[1]])
  OID POINTID WETLAND TPI200 TPI350 TPI500 TPI700 TPI900 TPI1000 TPI2000 TPI3000 TPI4000 TPI5000 TPI2500
1  -1       1 no wetl     70     67     55     50     48      46      53      47      49      63      48
2  -1       2 no wetl     37     42     35     29     32      16      17      35      49      63      26
3  -1       3 no wetl     45     55     45     39     41      41      53      47      49      63      48
4  -1       4 no wetl     46     58     51     43     46      36      54      47      49      62      49
5  -1       5 no wetl     58     55     53     49     47      46      54      47      49      62      49
6  -1       6 no wetl     56     53     51     49     46      46      54      47      49      61      49
```

`dput(datalist[[1]])` can be found [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ba28413206174a363fd5bcb95469bb8f20200804151443/4b4f5b) (txt file in wetransfer).

I already perfomed the `splsda.model` with two components using `lapply`, which results in the `model_list`:

```
library(mixOmics)

custom_splsda <- function(datalist, ncomp, keepX, ..., Xcols, Ycol){
  Y <- datalist[[Ycol]]
  X <- datalist[Xcols]
  res <- splsda(X, Y, ncomp = ncomp, keepX = keepX, ...)
  res
}

model_list <- lapply(datalist, custom_splsda, ncomp = 2, keepX = c(5, 5), Xcols = 4:8, Ycol = "WETLAND")
```

I want to visualise the individual observations against the two components and with the background, in order to have a plot for each dataframe (study area),
see for example:
[image: example background plot]

For one element (study area) of the list, this can be generated and saved as pdf by the following code:

```
background <- background.predict(model_list, comp.predicted = 2, dist = "max.dist")
pdf("backgroundPlot_studyarea1.pdf")
plotIndiv(model_list, comp = 1:2, group = datastudyarea1$WETLAND,
          ind.names = FALSE, title = "Maximum distance",
          legend = TRUE,  background = background,cex = 0.5)
dev.off()
```

I want to have this for all the 10 studyareas of the `datalist`, so having 10 background plots as pdf (backgroundPlot_studyarea1.pdf, backgroundPlot_studyarea2.pdf, etc) (or jpeg, also fine). How can I achieve this using `lapply`? Or do I have to use `for loop`?
I have tried many things, but none of these things seems to work...

Comment: Please `dput(datalist)` or `dput(datalist[[1]])` to make reproducible your issue and help you!

Comment: @Duck, the datalist is huge! All the dataframes contain more than 10-20 000 rows each! I can't manage to do `dput(model_list[[1]])`! But I edited the post and deliver the first rows of the first study area (first element/dataframe) of `datalist`! Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the sample data you provided, here a solution to save in one pdf each of the plots. For the sake of making reproducible the exercise, I have created `datalist` with the input you added. In your real problem you must have `datalist` with names in order to add the titles to plots. Also some data for plots was not available like `datastudyarea1` but it will not be difficult completing that part of the code for you. Here is the sketch:

```
library(mixOmics)
#Data
datalist <- list(df1 = structure(list(OID = c(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1), POINTID = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6), WETLAND = c("no wetl", "no wetl", "no wetl", 
"wetl", "wetl", "wetl"), TPI200 = c(70, 37, 45, 46, 58, 56), 
    TPI350 = c(67, 42, 55, 58, 55, 53), TPI500 = c(55, 35, 45, 
    51, 53, 51), TPI700 = c(50, 29, 39, 43, 49, 49), TPI900 = c(48, 
    32, 41, 46, 47, 46), TPI1000 = c(46, 16, 41, 36, 46, 46), 
    TPI2000 = c(53, 17, 53, 54, 54, 54), TPI3000 = c(47, 35, 
    47, 47, 47, 47), TPI4000 = c(49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49), TPI5000 = c(63, 
    63, 63, 62, 62, 61), TPI2500 = c(48, 26, 48, 49, 49, 49)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame"), df2 = structure(list(OID = c(-1, 
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1), POINTID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), WETLAND = c("no wetl", 
"no wetl", "no wetl", "wetl", "wetl", "wetl"), TPI200 = c(70, 
37, 45, 46, 58, 56), TPI350 = c(67, 42, 55, 58, 55, 53), TPI500 = c(55, 
35, 45, 51, 53, 51), TPI700 = c(50, 29, 39, 43, 49, 49), TPI900 = c(48, 
32, 41, 46, 47, 46), TPI1000 = c(46, 16, 41, 36, 46, 46), TPI2000 = c(53, 
17, 53, 54, 54, 54), TPI3000 = c(47, 35, 47, 47, 47, 47), TPI4000 = c(49, 
49, 49, 49, 49, 49), TPI5000 = c(63, 63, 63, 62, 62, 61), TPI2500 = c(48, 
26, 48, 49, 49, 49)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame"))
```

Now the code:

```
#Function
custom_splsda <- function(datalist, ncomp, keepX, ..., Xcols, Ycol){
  Y <- datalist[[Ycol]]
  X <- datalist[Xcols]
  res <- splsda(X, Y, ncomp = ncomp, keepX = keepX, ...)
  res
}

#Create model_list, you must have the object created
model_list <- lapply(datalist, custom_splsda,
                     ncomp = 2, keepX = c(5, 5),
                     Xcols = 4:8, Ycol = "WETLAND")

#Iterate to save
#Create pdf
pdf('Summaryplots.pdf',width = 14)
for(i in 1:length(model_list))
{
  #Create background
  background <- background.predict(model_list[[i]], 
                                   comp.predicted = 2, 
                                   dist = "max.dist")
  #Plot
  plotIndiv(model_list[[i]], comp = 1:2,
            ind.names = FALSE, title = paste0("Maximum distance ",names(model_list)[i]),
            legend = TRUE,  background = background,cex = 0.5)
}
#Turn devices off
dev.off()
```

That code will produce a pdf file with all plots saved on it. Just some details: `paste0("Maximum distance ",names(model_list)[i])` allows to add the title using the name of the object in `model_list`. Also in your original code you have `group = datastudyarea1$WETLAND`. I removed because I do not have data about that but you can add again to complement your desired output. Finally, I show the results saved in the pdf. Here is a pdf with two slides:

[image]

Comment: @Lies Also with the data you added I was able to answer the question you posted yesterday! You could check and see if that works for you :)